# In ASP.NET MVC4, where has application_error gone?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, event-handling

In MVC3, there was an Application_Error event handler in Global.asax.cs

MVC4 does not have this event handler.  Is there new functionality that is used to handle event errors like this in MVC4?

Comment: Can you please post some relevant code?  What caused the handler to be removed?  Are you comparing MVC3 to MVC4?

Comment: yes, I'm comparing mvc3 with mvc4

Comment: Are you saying VS doesn't automatically create this handler, or you create it and it never gets called? Please definie "does not have".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does have an Application_Error event, but like other events you have to actually create it yourself.  Just add it to global.asax

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: So I added this to my Global.asax.cs but it never gets called!

Comment: Well, it only gets called when there is an unhandled exception.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that I was returning an HttpStatusResult which doesn't trigger an exception. So I would have to throw an httpexception to get these custom error pages to work :/